# String interpretation in Python

Tags: string, search

If the user inputs "search" and "for" in the userinput i want it to return "search and for both have been input"

however, if the user inputs "search" and "information" in the userinput i want it to return "search and information both have been input"

The problem is, if the user inputs "search information", then python identifies the "for" in "information" and returns "search and for have been input"//. which is not what i want!

What to do?

Have a look at this image for understanding the problem described:
[image: blah]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that matters here is the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Because `in` is more binding than `and`, what actually happens in your condition is

```
if( "search" and ("for" in order )):
   ...
```

That means the second match is sufficient for entering the particular branch, because in Python strings are considered False if and only if they're empty. So your code is basically equal to

```
if "for" in order:
    print "For"
elif "information" in order:
    print "information"
```

In addition, the branches are evaluated in the order they're in the source code (that makes sense, see the "else if"). And since `for` is a substring of `information`, it's impossible for the second branch to occur. A simple fix would be to swap the two `if-else` branches (after resolving the previous issue). However, bear in mind that you need another approach for situations where the matches are of the same priority. e.g. `format` and `inform` in string `information`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your to look like this:

```
order=raw_input("you: ")
    if ("search" in order) and ("information" in order):
        print("Search and Information both in order")
    elif ("search" in order) and ("for" in order):
        print("Search and For both in order")
```

This way, it checks for "information" before "for". So "for" is only checked if order doesn't contain "information".

If you check in the python console, `"search" and "information"` is equivalent to `"information"` in python. So you have to check each word separately.

Comment: And you should post your raw code in your question, not in a picture.

Comment: sorry, i am quite a newbie, let me try that btw

Comment: This works but there is a new problem!!
If i just simply input "information" then it returns "search and information both in order"

which i dont want.. i want it to return only and only when both the strings are input by the user!!